# Images/Pictures which is fetched from the API and displayed in the screen is not captured while taking screenshots and sharing via social media

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, screenshot, html2canvas

Currently I'm working on my cordova app for android and there I need a functionality of taking screenshot and share in social media. So I used some lines of code and it worked by taking screenshot and sharing in social media, but it do not capture the image/picture coming from the **API** and displayed in the screen or in other words, it excludes the images/pictures, which is fetched from the **API** and displayed in the screen and takes the screenshot of remaining contents present in the screen. Can anyone help me with a solution to take screenshot properly with both image and content present in the screen and share via social media. Thanks in advance..!

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
      <div class="toolbar hideonshare" data-html2canvas-ignore="true" >
      <a href="#" class="link ">
      </a>
      <a  class="link" onclick="reportss();" >
      <img  src="img/share.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
      </a></div>
      <div class="screen"></div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
         function reportss() 
            {

                $(".hideonshare").hide();
                let region = document.querySelector("body");
                    html2canvas(region, {
                    onrendered: function(canvas) {
                        let pngUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
                        let img = document.querySelector(".screen");
                        img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");   
                        window.plugins.socialsharing.share("Download our app", 'Android filename', img.src, null);
                    },
                });

            }

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/SocialSharing.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason its not displaying is because you are treating a div element as a img element

change

```
      <div class="screen"></div>
```

To

```
      <img class="screen"></img>
```

Edited:

Try this code

```
function reportss() {

$(".hideonshare").hide();
var region = document.querySelector("body");
html2canvas(region, {
    logging: true,
    letterRendering: 1,
    useCORS: true,
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var pngUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
        var img = document.querySelector(".screen");
        img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        window.plugins.socialsharing.share("Download our app", 'Android filename', img.src, null);
    },
});}
```

Comment: Just FYI `<img />` elements are void and don't need a closing `</img>` tag - see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element